# How to store and retrieve .pdf, .exe file in SQL Server  2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010

I am currently working on a Windows Forms application (C#, VS 2010) and I need to create functionality that enables users to upload `.pdf`, `.exe` files into a SQL Server 2008 database and download them back.

The problem that I have is that the file downloaded from the database is always corrupted (except `.txt` file) even though they are the same size. And I have used `varbinary(MAX)` as the file type to store the data in the database.

Can anyone show me some example code for how to do this?

PS: I have researched for more than a week, but still cannot find a solution to my problem, can anyone please help? Any answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: **SHOW US YOUR CODE!** Otherwise, there's no way we can even begin to help you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below example there are a few assumptions made:

1. I'm using [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) for the database access. It extends **any** `IDbConnection` object.
2. I have a table in the database that has a definition as such `CREATE TABLE Data (Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, Data VARBINARY(MAX))`.
3. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) is the documentation for `ReadAllBytes`

So, obviously since you didn't provide anything surrounding your table structure you're going to have to change this code to meet you needs, but it will get you started.

### Writing It

```
this.connection.Open();

try
{
    var parameters = new
        {
            Data = File.ReadAllBytes(...);
        };
    return connection.Execute("INSERT INTO Data (Data) VALUES (@Data)", parameters);
}
finally
{
    this.connection.Close();
}
```

### Reading It

```
this.connection.Open();

try
{
    var parameters = new { Id = 1 };
    return connection.Query(
        "SELECT Data FROM dbo.Data WHERE Id = @Id", parameters)
        .Select(q => q.Data as byte[])
        .Single();
}
finally
{
    this.connection.Close();
}
```